# Error:(229, 12) java: exception org.springframework.web.client.HttpStatusCodeException has already been caught

Tags: java, rest, spring-boot, try-catch

Can't I use multiple catch ? First catch use for `RestClientException` and second use `HttpStatusCodeException`

```
 try {
         ResponseEntity<Stdo> responseEntity = restTemplate.exchange(theUrl, HttpMethod.POST, entity, Stdo.class);
  }catch (RestClientException ex) {
          if (ex.toString().contains("Connection timed out")) {
            }
  }catch(HttpStatusCodeException ex)
    {
        // get http status code
   }
}
```

**Error**

```
Error:(229, 12) java: exception org.springframework.web.client.HttpStatusCodeException has already been caught
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The hierarchy in the docs justify the error that you read.
 The [`HttpStatusCodeException`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/client/HttpStatusCodeException.html)

```
extends RestClientResponseException
```

and the [`RestClientResponseException`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/client/RestClientResponseException.html)

```
extends RestClientException
```

Hence the error. You can use those multiple `catch` in the reverse order.

```
catch(HttpStatusCodeException ex) {
    // get http status code
} catch (RestClientException ex) {
    if (ex.toString().contains("Connection timed out")) {...}
}
```